# ¿Por qué se muestra tarjeta de usuario ampliada antes de obtener dicho privilegio?

Tags: soporte, privilegios, interfaz-de-usuario

En la lista de privilegios se encuentra [Usuario Asentado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) que da los beneficios de

> - Pueden ver el recuento de votos en las publicaciones.
> - Una tarjeta de usuario ampliada que mostrará información de perfil adicional.

Este privilegio se otorga al ganar 1000 puntos de reputación.

Actualmente, aunque no puedo ver un recuento de votos, sí que puedo ver la tarjeta de usuario ampliada, cuando claramente no tengo dicha reputación.

Y eso que, solo hasta hoy caigo en cuenta de la necesidad de 1000 puntos para ver dicha tarjeta, pues la vengo viendo sin problemas desde hace un buen tiempo (tal vez con 700 de rep o menos).

Lo probé en el avatar de usuario en una pregunta, una respuesta y lista de usuarios.

[image: Imagen de prueba]

**¿Es este comportamiento un bug? ¿Le sucede a alguien más con reputación inferior a mil?**

Comment: Creo que estás confundido. El privilegio que se obtiene si no me equivoco es que **otros** puedan ver tu tarjeta ampliada, no que tu puedas ver la de los demas...

Comment: @Pikoh viéndolo así creo que tienes toda la razón, no sé porqué pensé que era al contrario

Comment: A lo mejor me confundí con el primer privilegio que dice `puedes ver...`  Así mismo, lo asimilé con el segundo privilegio

Comment: No pasa nada, es normal la confusión :)

Comment: Sí la verdad es que la explicación presta a confusión. Algo así como _Una tarjeta de usuario ampliada mostrará información adicional de tu perfil_ podría entenderse mejor.

Comment: @fedorqui me parece más claro de este modo

Comment: Pues nada, que alguien haga un PR en el [repo del Centro de Ayuda en Github](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages) y sugiera la modificación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, la redacción de la página de ayuda posiblemente no sea la mas adecuada y puede llevar a confusión.

El privilegio *Una tarjeta de usuario ampliada que mostrará información de perfil adicional*, que se obtiene al alcanzar los 1000 puntos de reputación, se refiere a que cualquier usuario del sitio podrá ver la tarjeta ampliada del usuario que alcanza dicha reputación, no que puedan verse las tarjetas de otros a partir de esa reputación.

Dicho de otra forma, todos los usuarios del sitio pueden ver las tarjetas ampliadas, pero solo los usuarios con mas de 1000 puntos pueden disponer de ellas.

Comment: Si, puede que a veces por temas de traducción o regiones, la información que se brinda puede ser un poco ambigua. Espero no ser el único que tuvo esta duda jajaja. Muchas gracias por tu aclaración

Comment: Listo! agregado a GitHub!

Comment: Muchas gracias @g3rv4