# Mejoremos el artículo del Centro de Ayuda sobre "Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"

Tags: discusión, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

En Meta.SO ha habido un debate reciente sobre el artículo del Centro de Ayuda *Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable*, en [Can we please get the “How to create an MCVE” help page updated, to state that a link to a GitHub project is generally NOT an acceptable MCVE?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380194/1983854)

El tema que se ha sacado a colación es que no se estaba diciendo que todo el código debe estar en la pregunta, por lo que en cierto modo legitimaba que la gente enlazara un repositorio propio o similar.

El CM Shog9 ha hecho unos cambios que dejan claro que sí debe estar todo en la pregunta y que debe ser completo. Puede verse en [su respuesta a la pregunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380260/1983854) y ya vemos la versión actualizada en el Help Center de Stack Overflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Sería interesante actualizar nuestro artículo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve con esta sección, pues es frecuente ver enlaces a repositorios en preguntas de SOes. Además, creo que iría bien pulir un poco la traducción pues contiene bastantes erratas, así como indicar que tenemos [Fiddles: Lista de páginas que podemos usar para probar código y sus características](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83).

Dejo pues una respuesta wiki para que editemos entre todos y finalmente hagamos un PR en el repositorio que mantiene g3rv4 para tal efecto (https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages).

Comment: Y ya que estáis leyendo, [a ver si alguien se anima a hacer una PR para mejorar el artículo sobre la tarjeta ampliada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3910/por-qué-se-muestra-tarjeta-de-usuario-ampliada-antes-de-obtener-dicho-privilegi/3912#comment15066_3910)

Comment: Veo que lo que se ha modificado principalmente es la sección _Complete_. La nueva versión es mucho más específica y clara. Me parecería bien copiarla tal cual.

Comment: Por cierto, no veo el articulo sobre la tarjeta ampliada en el github?

Comment: @Pikoh oh, cierto. g3rv4 comentó que los iría añadiendo a demanda. Si creas un _issue_ él lo añade en un plis, lo tiene super estructurado.

Comment: Hecho: https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/issues/35

Comment: Aunque, ahora que leo la pagina de ayuda, aunque la descripción inicial del privilegio puede ser mejorable, la verdad es que la sección que lo explica a mi me parece bastante clara...

Comment: @Pikoh sí bueno, lo comenté por aquello de que esa parte no se entendía demasiado bien y que ya que tenemos tan a mano hacer los cambios, pues que se podía hacer.

Comment: Si. Bueno, ya que está el issue creado, trataremos de modificar esa frase para que sea mas clara

Comment: listo! el artículo está en GitHub

Comment: ¡Genial! Me ganaste a publicarlo estaba pensando en hacer lo mismo, ¿cómo iremos manejando las propuestas? ¿o nada mas haremos una traducción de lo que se menciona en [so]?

Comment: @KacosPro yo empezaría por una traducción literal del artículo de SO. Si luego se quiere improvisar y añadir más cosas, bien.

Answer (score 2):

Versión actual del artículo [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

---

Cuando preguntas sobre un problema causado por tu código, recibirás mejores respuestas si proporcionas el código necesario para reproducir el problema.  Ese código debe de ser:

- …Mínimo - usa la menor cantidad posible de código para reproducir el problema
- …Completo - asegúrate de proporcionar todas las partes necesarias para reproducir el problema
- …Verificable - prueba el código que aportas para asegurarte de que sirve para reproducir el problema

### Mínimo

Cuanto más código haya, menos probable será que la gente encuentre el problema. Optimiza tu ejemplo de una de estas formas:

1. **Vuelve a empezar de cero.** Crea un nuevo programa, agregando solamente lo que es necesario para ver el problema.  Esto tiende a ser más rápido en sistemas vastos donde ya conoces la fuente del problema.  También es útil si no puedes publicar el código original por razones legales o éticas.
2. **Divide y conquista.** Cuando tienes un poco de código pero el motivo del problema no es claro, empieza a quitar un poco de código a la vez hasta que el problema desaparezca - entonces añade la ultima parte de nuevo.

### Mínimo *y* legible

Mínimo no implica *breve* - no sacrifiques la comunicación por motivos de brevedad.  Sé consistente con los nombres y el formato. No olvides tampoco incluir comentarios si necesitas explicar partes del código. La mayoría de editores de código tienen atajos para formatear - ¡encuéntralos y usalos! Además, **no uses tabuladores** - se ven bien en tu editor pero no en Stack Overflow. Aquí, crean un desastre.

### Completo

Asegúrate de que toda la información necesaria para reproducir el problema está incluida.

- Algunos estarán listos para cargar las partes e intentar probar el código antes de aportar sus respuestas o sugerencias.
- El problema puede que no esté en la parte que te imaginas, sino que puede estar escondido en otra parte.

Si el problema requiere código del lado de los servidores y archivos de configuraciones XML, inclúyelos también.  Si la página web requiere HTML, JavaScript y CSS, incluye lo necesario.

### Verificable

Para poder ayudar a solucionar tu problema, la gente deberá saber que *existe*:

- **Describe el problema.** “No me funciona“ no es una explicación útil.  Dinos cuál debería ser el comportamiento esperado.  Cuéntanos cuál es la redacción exacta del error que se produce y en qué linea se está produciendo.  Pon un resumen breve del problema en el título de la pregunta.
- **Elimina todas las cuestiones no necesarias al problema.** Si tu pregunta no es acerca de  un error de compilación, asegúrate de que no haya errores de ese tipo.  Usa un programa como [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) para validar lenguajes interpretados. Todo el HTML y XML debe ser [verificado](http://validator.w3.org/).
- **¡Asegúrate de que el ejemplo reporta el problema en la actualidad!** Si solucionaste el problema inadvertidamente mientras preparas el aporte pero no lo pruebas de nuevo, sería bueno saberlo antes de pedir ayuda.

Para mas ayuda en como depurar tu programa para crear un ejemplo mínimo, [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) tiene un muy buen articulo de blog sobre este tema: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) <sub>en inglés</sub>.